# kernel space of linear combination of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $N\times N$ matrices so that for every $x$ and $y$, $xA+yB$ has a kernel of dimension at least $2$.

Is it necessarily true that $\ker(A)\cap\ker(B)$ has dimension at least $2$?

Comment: Nope. For a linear combination of $A$ and $B$ to have a chance at having a kernel of dimension less than $2$, it is necessary that the images of $A$ and $B$ span a space of codimension less than $2$. It is possible to choose $A$ and $B$ so that, although the intersection of their kernels is $1$-dimensional, the span of their images has codimension $2$. Consider, for example, $A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Okay. But now I think i have to change the problem a bit. Let us consider not the kernel, but the range. For two arbitrary matrices $A$ and $B$, i guess one can always find two numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $xA + yB$'s range is the span of the ranges of A and B.

Comment: again, no, for essentially the dual reason. Just take the transpose of my counterexample above.